# Let $H, K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$. Show that $|HgK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|K \cap g^{-1}Hg|}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H, K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$. Show that $$|HgK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|K \cap g^{-1}Hg|}$$

Ok, so $HgK=hgk$ where $h \in H, k \in K$

$|g^{-1}HgK|=|HgK|$

$HgK \to g^{-1}(Hgk)$

$x \to g^{-1}x$

Now, I'm assuming that I am trying to use $\frac{|K||H|}{|K\cap H|}$ I'm just not seeing it

Comment: Ask yourself: when does $hgk = h'gk'$? You're almost there-try using the subgroup $H' = g^{-1}Hg$.

Comment: @cele-that's one possibility, but not the only one. What if $kk'^{-1} = g^{-1}h^{-1}h'g$? Isn't that saying that we have some element of $K$ that is also in $g^{-1}Hg$?

Comment: @DavidWheeler I would assume that its telling me that they are either disjoint or equal

Comment: @cele- I have no idea what you mean by "they".

Comment: @DavidWheeler, the cosets, say HgK, HhK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already established that $|HgK| = |g^{1}HgK|$.

Set $H' = g^{-1}Hg$.

Then $|HgK| = |H'K| = \dfrac{|H'||K|}{|H'\cap K|} = \dfrac{|H||K|}{|g^{-1}Hg \cap K|}$, as desired.

Comment: oh wow, I cant believe that was all that I was missing. I'm only learning this topic and I was viewing examples that were taking a much more difficult approach